# Help finding PWM IC with marking on device 'GLS'. Package of device is SOT23 - 6

Tags: pwm, switch-mode-power-supply

I am trying to do some reverse engineering on 12V DC wall adapter where I found this 6 pin PWM IC. I am unable to find any of it's details on google.
So requesting if anyone could help me in finding the device name.[image]

Answer (score 4):

It's an [AP3125AKTR-G1](https://www.diodes.com/assets/Datasheets/AP3125A_V_L_R.pdf) Green mode PWM controller from BCD/Diodes Incorporated.

[image]

Comment: Thankyou sir for your effort. It's really going to help me now.